# Can you put different CPUs in a dual-cpu motherboard?

Tags: central-processing-unit, hardware, multiprocessing

I have an ASUS KCMA-D8 motherboard with two Socket C32 CPU sockets. Only one is used right now. Can if put a different (better) CPU in the other socket and have the motherboard use both? Or do motherboards with two CPU sockets require that both CPUs be identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you [technically *CAN* do this](https://serverfault.com/questions/618974/is-it-possible-to-influence-the-way-cpus-are-enumerated-under-linux)... but it's just not a good idea.

I'd plan for equally-spec'd CPUs if you ever need to upgrade.